# problem 'Tkinter as tk' imported but unused

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

read the related questions but I did not understand much, I could say that nothing, I'm aware I'm in a mechanics course at the university, and I have to use a python code for a certain calculation, the thing that throws me problems but execute but I am intrigued by the error that points, and I searched as a resolution but I do not get the solution so I found this forum and I hope to get to it, the code is as follows:

[imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfhrG.png)

[imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m784r.png)

[imagen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SICuG.png)

[imagen 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DODVQ.png)

[imagen 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0fZq.png)

https://www.mediafire.com/file/uvuyc2v822i3h9b/atwood_viscous_fluid_solver.py/file

I would appreciate it if you can help me, and that the translator helps you enough.

Comment: Never post image of code.

Comment: Pictures of code are absolutely useless.

Comment: To solve this, Change: `import Tkinter as tk` to `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @U9-Forward *Change: import Tkinter as tk to import tkinter as tk*... This is incorrect. The OP simply needs to apply the `tk.` prefix to the widgets.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is you are not applying the `tk.` prefix to your widgets.

For example if you do `From Tkinter import *` then you can create a widget like this:

```
Button(root, text="OK").pack()
```

However if you use the `import Tkinter as tk` then you will need to use the `tk.` prefix for all widget creation.

Like this:

```
tk.Button(root, text="OK").pack()
```

So fall all your buttons, labels, entries and any other widget you are setting up use the `tk.` prefix and it will work.

For this line:

```
ux = us[:,0]
```

You do not use `ux` down the road in your code so the IDE is telling you that `ux` is unused.

All that said please in the future place your code directly in the question. Using an image makes it hard to test your code as we cannot copy paste into our IDE and test.